# Get simple JSON Parameter from a JSON request in JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

The client/browser makes a JSON request to my rest resource (the content-type of the request is `application/json` and the corresponding REST method is `@Consumes("application/json")` annotated).

```
@Path("/process-something")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@HandleDefaultExceptions
public AResponse processSomething(List<Long>) {

}
```

The JSON body consists  of some simple types, like `List<Long>` or `String`.

Is there a simple possibility to get JSON parameters injected just annotating it somehow, similar to `@FormParam` in the case of a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request?
I would like some other easier solutions than decoding the JSON String with Jackson's `ObjectMapper` or Jettison's `JSONObject`.

Comment: what framework are you using for jaxrs implementation ?, there are many frameworks out there which provide JSON support although only annotation is not enough, you will have to map appropriate providers but thats not a big deal. Refer Jersey, Apache CXF

Comment: Jersey is what I use. I hope by Mapping you do not mean creating ObjectMapper's or some other instances of objects (see the last part of the question) ...

Comment: no i mean that you will have to provide an entry either in web.xml or some another config file which will tell jersey to use json support. see this : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json  - And these are the easier solutions !

Comment: @Sikorski You mean actually a solution like the one provided in the answer of TheArchitect?

Comment: yes, in addition to that i think you will have to give pojo-json support sort of entry in your config file also. Please refer to link given above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a Java class that reflects the data model of your JSON object and annotate it with JAXB's @XmlRootElement. You can map the attributes to custom JSON key name with @XmlElement annotations, e.g.:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyJSONOject{
    @XmlElement(name="json-key-name")
    public String attribute;
}
```

Then Jersey can decode the JSON object for you transparently and voila!

```
@Path("/process-something")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public AResponse processSomething(MyJSONOject json) {
    log.fine(json.attribute);
}
```

Comment: Although I expected an easier way, such as getting the parameter injected with an annotation (see my answer), I mark this as an answer, as this is still a better solution than decoding it manually with Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrst/index.html) there are 6 parameter-based annotations used to extract parameters from a request, and no one seems to be for JSON parameters.

Comment: why have you written this as an answer ?

Comment: Because this could be the answer... at least there is no annotation in the JAX-RS standard that extracts the JSON parameter.

Comment: just what do you think @Consumes("application/json") does ?

Comment: The annotation says that the annotated method processes ONLY requests with Content-Type: application/json in the header. Did I miss anything?

Comment: that annotation tells the framework to convert json into a pojo or raw JSONObject just go through the link i have provided above and things should start working for you.